# Putting select element to div with z-index position to Highcharts container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'd like to place dropdown (html select) to element with position: absolute, but the problem that when i push select to open menu it doesn't open. The button pushes but it doesn't open.

I have board (dive element) on on this board there are a lot of tiles (divs) with css like:

```
position:absolute
z-index: 2
```

And one of them contains chart library, called Highcharts. Highcharts container has z-index = 0

So it looks like

```
<div class='tile'> //position: absolute, z-index = 2
     <div class='highcharts-container'> //position: relative, z-index = 0
          <div class='controlPanel'>   //position:absolute, no z-index
              <button 1> //relative
              <button 2> //relative
              <wanna place here dropdown, so select> //!!!my dropdown
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried to just put dropdown in div container with position relative, but without any result.

My code of addition:

```
 var chooseContainer = $('<div class="rangeContainer"></div>');
 var chooseRange = $('<select class="rangeDropdown"></select>');
 var element1 = $('<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>');
 var element2 = $('<option value="saab">Saab</option>');
 chooseContainer.append(chooseRange);
 chooseRange.append(element1);
 chooseRange.append(element2);
 chartControlPanel.append(chooseContainer);
 chartControlPanel.append(addBtn);
 chartControlPanel.append(resetBtn);
 chartControlPanel.append(legendBtn);
```

Edit (drawing of how it looks):
[image: dropdown problem]

Thanks in advance! :)

JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/akorovin/cq2be/

Probably it's a problem with highcharts or with my css

Comment: @vivekshaushi http://jsfiddle.net/bMkHd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fusher at Highcharts Forum.

His message:

> Highcharts container click events are binded, so adding dropdown inside highcharts-container isn't the best idea. I think it's easier to add this directly to the container and the position dropdown, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bMkHd/8/

So it means. Do not add anything to .highcharts-container. Better to put it on the div that contains .highcharts-container, like:

```
 $('#container').highcharts(...)
 $('#container').append(myDropdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have seems to work fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/8uU2w/ this is only assuming that the variable for  " chartControlPanel " is the " highcharts-container " element. See if there is a logical error with how " chartControlPanel " is defined. That is the one that seems to be the issue. Also check your javascript console for any noticeable errors that appear related.

```
chartControlPanel.append(chooseContainer);
```

->  http://jsfiddle.net/8uU2w/